# How to test a site "from" another country?

Tags: testing, proxy, ip, country

I just had a call from norway saying that there is a weird domain redirect that ends up in a 404 error,

how can I simulate that I am in another country or replicate this error?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

There is a service called [Tunnel Bear](https://www.tunnelbear.com/download) , they allow you to **install small application on computer, choose country where you want to "visit from"** and then look at web sites as user from that country.

Also, there are lots of premium VPN solutions (i.e. [ExpressVPN](https://www.expressvpn.com/)) which can be used to simulate this. It's pretty intuitive and easy to use. I think they have free account with some limited bandwith. @Carl_Whalley, if you want give it a shoot, hope it helps.

Finally, you can use [Hoxx VPN proxy](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/hoxx-vpn-proxy/) (installed as an free add-on for Mozilla) where you can choose multiple locations and change your IP.

Comment: Awesome recommendation. Don't even need to install the application, just added the Chrome extension, super easy to set up and use.

Comment: Also using a proxy is a good solution:
1. Search for proxy IPs from the country you want to visit your website with
2. search how to setup a proxy for your browser

Comment: Regarding [Tunnel Bear](https://www.tunnelbear.com/download) it is important to point that has available only few countries.

Comment: BrowserStack has this feature. Read more here - https://www.browserstack.com/guide/test-websites-from-different-countries

Comment: @ShanEapenKoshy I'm not sure BrowserStack offers real server locations, or if they're simply simulating it.

Answer (score 18):

Best and simple solution, works perfectly to me. http://www.locabrowser.com/

Comment: Doesn't include South America.. only a few countries... Would work for OP, but not others.

Comment: Still a great tool even ho it's limited to few countries, no registration needed. Russia seems to be not working at the moment.

Answer (score 9):

Try this site to test from different locations
http://www.webpagetest.org/

Comment: This only gives back some statistics, this is not useful to really test the page "from other country" in any way

Comment: What about https://www.geoscreenshot.com/

Comment: Works great for us. They offer screenshots, videos, and a lot more now.

Comment: 2023-12: geoscreenshot.com has shut down.

Answer (score -1):

best way to do something like this is by using some **proxy service**.

List of web proxy services can be found at http://proxy.org/proxies_sorted.shtml , they are sorted by country.

Simply, find country you like (for example Norway), select any proxy and open web site with that proxy. It will be like you're visitor from that country. :)

Good luck

Comment: That link is dead. Any others?

Comment: Hi Carl, I added new answer with one service that I recently started using, hope it helps.